# reverse iterator for binary search tree error at compile time that says "no matching function call for operator=()"

Tags: c++

I am trying to nest a reverse_iterator class into my Binary search tree here is the class:

```
template <class T>
class BST
{
public:
   BST() { root = NULL; numElements = 0; }
   BST(const BST <T> & rhs);
   ~BST() { /*deleteBtree(root)*/ }
   BST & operator = (const BST <T> & rhs);
   int size() const { return numElements; }
   bool empty() const
   {
      if ( root == NULL )
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   void clear() { root = NULL; }

   void insert( const T & t);

   class iterator;
   iterator find(const T & t);

   iterator begin() { return iterator (root);}
   iterator end() {return iterator (NULL); }
   void erase(iterator it);

   class reverse_iterator;
   reverse_iterator rfind(const T & t);
 reverse_iterator rbegin() {return reverse_iterator (NULL); }
   reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator (root); }
   void rerase(reverse_iterator it);

private:


   void deleteNode(BNode <T> del, bool right);
   void deletlBinaryTree(BNode <T>  del);
   void copyBinaryTree(BNode <T> src, BNode <T> dest);


   BNode <T> * root;
   int numElements;


};
```

and Here is my reverse_iterator class:

```
template <class T>
class BST <T> :: reverse_iterator
{
public:
   reverse_iterator() { pNode = NULL; }
   reverse_iterator(BNode <T> * p) { pNode = p; }
   reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator & rhs) {*this = rhs; }

   reverse_iterator & operator =(const reverse_iterator & it)
   {
      this->pNode = it.pNode;
      return *this;
   }
   bool operator ==(const reverse_iterator & it) const
   { return it.pNode != this->pNode;}

   bool operator !=(const reverse_iterator & it) const
   { return it.pNode == this->pNode;}

   reverse_iterator & operator ++();

   reverse_iterator & operator --();

   T & operator *() const { return pNode->data; }

private:
   BNode <T> * pNode;
};
```

in my main function, I am trying to use my iterator in this loop:

```
for (it = tree2.rbegin(); it != tree2.rend(); --it)
         cout << "  " << *it;
      cout << "  }\n";
```

I can not change the main function so I need my class reverse_iterator function to match the call of the main function. But I am getting this error:

```
assignment09.cpp:225:30: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘BST<double>::iterator’ and ‘BST<double>::reverse_iterator’)
       for (it = tree2.rbegin(); it != tree2.rend(); --it)
```

I am not done writing all the functions in the Binary Search Tree class, I am just trying to get the program to compile at this point. any suggestions?
I am getting this error message:

Comment: `for (it ...` how is `it` declared?

Comment: Also, even if `it` had the correct type, `--it` is wrong. A reverse_iterator should be incremented to go backwards. That's why it's called a _reverse_ iterator.

Comment: Writing your own reverse iterators is error-prone. You can just do `using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>`.

Answer (score 1):

> But I am getting this error: assignment09.cpp:225:30: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘BST::iterator’ and ‘BST::reverse_iterator’)

It says that there is no `operator=` where the operators are `BST::iterator` and `BST::reverse_iterator`.

In other words you are trying to assign a `BST::reverse_iterator` to a variable of type `BST::iterator`. Since they are different classes, you can't do that. Store your `BST::reverse_iterator` in a variable of type `BST::reverse_iterator`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Could you provide an example of how to store BST::reverse_iterator in a variable of type BST::reverse_iterator?@ user253751

Comment: @Megan That is a very basic question and I'm not sure how you got this far without understanding it. Is English your main language? What you are trying to do now is the same as `int i = "hello";` and the fix is obviously `std::string i = "hello";`

Answer (score 1):

user253751 correctly addresses the problem, but I think there are other solutions:

- One way could be having `reverse_iterator` inherit from `iterator` since a `reverse_iterator` **is** an `iterator`. This would allow you to reduce some code (I assume there are a lot of overlapping between the two classes for everything that is not related to the order of traversing.)
- Another way is to refactor your class and issue an instance of `iterator` both for forward and reversed traversing. This would work if you refactor your `iterator` class to work for both directions based on how it is instantiated.